# Ubuntu 18.04 Audio Jack Re-tasking Issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 18.04, alsa, headphones

I recently moved to Ubuntu 18.04 from Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to re-task my **Rare Blue Audio Jack** as **Headphone Jack [Line Out(front)]**. I did this in 16.04 using *hdajackretask*. But when I am trying to Override the jack in my current OS, I am getting the following error:

[image]

My terminal output looks like-

```
~$ sudo hdajackretask
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory
0x11 0x99430130
0x14 0x01014010
0x15 0x01011012
0x16 0x01016011
0x17 0x01012014
0x18 0x01a19040
0x19 0x02a19050
0x1a 0x01014010
0x1b 0x02214020
0x1e 0x4037d500
1
```

I tried *alsamixer* automute disabling and pulseausio restart. None worked.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Same here, using Ubuntu 18.04.

The solution is quite simple. **Don't run hdajackretask with sudo**. Just run it under your own account. It will ask you for your own password to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

Close any program that is using the device like alsamixer, etc., and then try again.

Comment: Or pulseaudio or pipewire.

Answer (score 0):

use terminal command `aplay -l` to list sound playback hardware devices

devices should show as available "Subdevices: 1/1"
"Subdevices: 0/1" would indicate device is busy, probably in use by Pulseaudio

got to Pulseaudio Volume Control Configuration tab (`pavucontrol -t 5`)
set all listed devices to "Off"

`aplay -l` should now confirm device available and hdaretask can apply settings

Change configuration back to enable audio hardware in Pulseaudio when done

Comment: Doesn't work. And more importantly, I can't reset my old pavucontrol config

Comment: what was response  to `aplay -l`?
don't understand why you cannot reset changes made in pavucontrol, did you clear any settings in hdajackrestask that could be Pulseaudio starting?